# Spock interaction does not work if defined with 'as'

Tags: groovy, spock

I've written the following specification:

```
class Spec extends Specification {

    def 'does not work if interaction declared as Set without parens'() {
        given:
        def holder = Mock(Holder)
        def expected = [1, 2, 3, 3]

        when:
        def output = holder.value()

        then:
        output == [1, 2, 3] as Set
//        1 * holder.value() >> expected.toSet()      // 1
        1 * holder.value() >> expected as Set       // 2
//        1 * holder.value() >> (expected as Set)     // 3
    }

    class Holder {
        def value() {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem lies in the fact that it works only if `holder.value()` interaction is defined as in line *1* or *3*. When it's defined like in the line *2* it fails with the following error:

```
Condition not satisfied:

output == [1, 2, 3] as Set
|      |
null   false
```

Why? It seems that there might be some parser error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no parser error but you made a programming error. According to the rules of [Groovy operator precedence](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_operator_precedence) `>>` has a higher precedence than `as`, which effectively makes your faulty code equivalent to

```java
((1 * holder.value()) >> expected) as Set
```

Spock implements a DSL for testing, but the code is still Groovy. ;-)

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I was looking for! I know it's still groovy ;)